# Como posso centralizar um banner?

Tags: css, wordpress

Tenho esse código abaixo e estou inserindo no plug-in do wordpress. O banner aparece no site mas não está centralizado, está aparecendo colado à esquerda. Alguém pde por favor me passar esse código de novo só para colar dentro do plugin e já aparecer centralizado o banner no site?

```
<ins class="bookingaff" data-aid="1295946" data-target_aid="1295944" data-prod="banner" data-width="728" data-height="90" data-banner_id="56128" data-lang="pt-BR">
    <!-- Anything inside will go away once widget is loaded. -->
    <a href="//www.booking.com?aid=1295944">Booking.com</a>
</ins>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(d, sc, u) {
      var s = d.createElement(sc), p = d.getElementsByTagName(sc)[0];
      s.type = 'text/javascript';
      s.async = true;
      s.src = u + '?v=' + (+new Date());
      p.parentNode.insertBefore(s,p);
      })(document, 'script', '//aff.bstatic.com/static/affiliate_base/js/flexiproduct.js');
</script>
```

Comment: Ja tentou usar `margin: 0 auto;`?

Comment: oi, não sei como mudar linhas nesse código. onde tenho que colocar isso só que você falou e o que tenho que tirar no código atual? agradeço demais!

Answer (score 1):

Tal como o @RafaelAugusto referiu em cima, basta adicionar uma `<div>` antes e adicione `margin: 0 auto;` e `text-align:center;`, ou seja

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;text-align:center;">
<ins class="bookingaff" data-aid="1295946" data-target_aid="1295944" data-prod="banner" data-width="728" data-height="90" data-banner_id="56128" data-lang="pt-BR">
    <!-- Anything inside will go away once widget is loaded. -->
    <a href="//www.booking.com?aid=1295944">Booking.com</a>
</ins>
</div>
```

Comment: agora ficou perfeito! muito obrigada de coração a vocês 2, salvaram meu dia! estou ainda começando e várias dúvidas surgem, agradeço demais a boa vontade e excelente trabaho de vocês, que mereçam coisas boas em dobro!!! obrigada :)))

Comment: @user92734 Declare a pergunta como aceite por favor e bom código!

Answer (score 0):

Tenta aí

```
<div align="center">
código do banner
</div>
```

Ou

```
<center>
código do banner
</center>
```

exp... BANEER CRU `<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.adexchangetracker.com/a/display.php?r=1966211"></script>`

BANER CENTRALIZADO

```
<center><script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.adexchangetracker.com/a/display.php?r=1966211"></script></center>
```

EXP 2
BANNER CRU

```
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.adexchangetracker.com/a/display.php?r=1966211"></script>
```

BANNER CENTRALIZADO

```
<div align="center"><script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.adexchangetracker.com/a/display.php?r=1966211"></script></div>
```

Comment: Seu codigo não fez muito sentido, edite a resposta e explique melhor esses códigos.